# Having a library as a submodule in combination with a Unity game engine project

Tags: c#, git, unity-game-engine

I have created a library, with its own git repo. I want to include it in a Unity3D project, but I also want to be able to adjust the library from within the working solution.

## Context

#### Unity

Unity automatically (re-)creates its `.sln` and `.csproj` files, so

- I can't set the library `.csproj` as a reference there. In order to use a DLL with Unity, it has to be put in a special "Plugins" folder and will then be included in the auto-generated files.
- it's impractical to use Unity's auto-generated `.sln` for... well, anything other than the Unity project itself.

#### Library

The library has its own git repo, included as a git submodule. I understand that I can change the output path of `mylib.csproj` to point to that Unity "Plugins" folder, but then that would be saved in the library git repo - which would make the whole repo moot by having it only work for this project.

## Current State

I put the library and Unity project inside a "master solution" and currently have the following structure for that:

```
-mylib (solution folder, but also a file system folder containing the git submodule)
    -mylib.csproj
    -unittests.csproj (for mylib)
-Unity (solution folder, but also a file system folder containing the Unity project)
    -Assembly-CSharp.csproj
    -etc., all the auto-(re-)generated files
-unittests.csproj (for the Unity project)
```

## Goal

What I want to achieve is being able to build `mylib.csproj` and have its DLL automatically be put into that "Plugins" folder in the Unity project. Given the restrictions mentioned in the "Context" part, is this possible?

I am currently using Visual Studio Community 2017 to set this up, but it has to be possible to work on the end product with other IDEs, especially JetBrains Rider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Avoid library and Unity .csproj

I now found a solution, much less involved than I thought it would be.

I added a new, empty project to the master solution - I ended up literally calling it `BuildToUpdateLibraries` - and then did the following things:

- set the output type to "Class library"
  This way, the project doesn't need a `main` method, so we can build without actually having any code at all - a build will just create an empty BuildToUpdateLibraries.dll.
- added the `mylib` project as a reference
  This will copy the `mylib.dll` to the BuildToUpdateLibraries output folder.*

Now we can freely edit the `BuildToUpdateLibraries.csproj` file and will neither make the libraries unusable elsewhere nor have Unity overwrite it on every rebuild.

## Copying to the plugins folder

Now, the one last issue here is that when building, we get more than we want.
There is the useless `BuildToUpdateLibraries.dll`, but also *every* .dll `mylib` depends on*. You might actually need (some of) these, but in my case it was the `UnityEngine.dll`. That .dll is part of Unity and importing it again probably only leads to problems.

Thus, setting the output folder of BuildToUpdateLibraries to the Unity Plugins folder is not an optimal solution. However, as we can now freely edit the BuildToUpdateLibraries .csproj, we can just add post-build events. I added the following line in the post-build events to copy the file:

```
xcopy "$(TargetDir)mylib.dll" "$(SolutionDir)Unity\Assets\Plugins\MyLib"
```

Now when I build `BuildToUpdateLibraries`, it will first build `mylib` and then build `BuildToUpdateLibraries` with the `mylib.dll` included. Finally, it will copy the file to the Unity plugins folder.

*There *is* an option to not include a .dll in the output folder, but default behaviour is to copy and you would have to do that for every file.

Comment: Right now, I am in the same boat with the same issue. Unfortunately though it happens that Rider integration with Unity itself behaves erroneous when having a custom solution file that includes the Unity `.csproj` and custom libraries somewhere else. Currently I have a `Submodules` folder in the root folder of the Unity repository which contains my libraries. Then I have created symlinks using `mklink /D Foo ..\..\Submodules\Foo\Source` inside the `~/Assets/Plugins` folder. The integration works again and all my custom libraries are listed in `Assembly-CSharp-firstpass`. [1 / 2]

Comment: So basically I have only one Rider window open with both the Unity code and my libraries listed as folders inside one project. The downside is presumably that the symlink won't work under macOS while the pro is that you don't have to manually initiate a DLL build since Unity will automatically watch for changes inside the Plugins folder and recompile the `firstpass` project to catch those. And of course another downside is Submodules in general. [2 / 2]

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic Yeah indeed, the rider plugin wasn't important to me but solid cross-compatibility, especially after going through git,  was. I used submodules directly in the plugin folder (no symlinks) before, but with every library having an additional unit test project, it became very convoluted and the paths all ended up being very long, it was just very chaotic. If you have one stable development environment, your solution sounds like the right way to go.

Comment: Symlinks are a pain - while they work on Linux and macOS, Windows can't recreate them properly since you need elevated privileges and `core.symlinks` set to true which is a PITA. Furthermore I am running a GitLab CI Runner on my local PC to compile the game and it cannot create the links since it's not running with elevated privileges. In fact, even though my approach is cleaner, I have to come up with something else since I cannot bother fiddling around with all those edge cases wherein links cannot be created anymore. Another issue are cross-references. [1 / 2]

Comment: I wanted to create a `Shared` library and `Client` as well as `Server` and drop `Shared` and `Client` in the plugins folder. Of course if I add `Shared` as another submodule inside of `Client` which is already a submodule, then Unity will most likely have duplicates for `Shared`. I guess I'll try to place only the `Client` library with its `Shared` submodule inside of `Plugins`. Cleaning up the submodule configuration won't be fun, but I guess I have to give it a try. [2 / 2]

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic Yeah it sounds like the hassle is not worth the advantage you get from it. By the way, by now I kicked the libraries out of there again. In the end, there were too many things you could do wrong. The libs are now still their own repos with their own unit testing etc, I only add their DLLs to the Unity plugin folder. The idea is that as libraries, once they were done, they are not changing much - and for these little changes every now and then, copying the DLL manually is acceptable. I admit that one of the libraries changed a lot, but that is how i noticed that it [cont.]

Comment: was actually _very_ tied to the project and having it as it as an external library didn't make a lot of sense. Looking at your project that way, it seems like e.g. a library to do your network stuff could be used by your client, your server, and other projects. OTOH, a `Shared` lib for _everything that is the same between client and server_ is not going to give you a lot of re-usability. Anyway, I'm afraid SO doesn't condone discussions, the Unity forums are only good for beginner questions... I'd advise you to post your situation to https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/, lot of know how there.